# how to use pyspark to read orc file

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

there are two types compress file format for spark. one is parquet, it's very easy to read:

```
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
hiveCtx = HiveContext(sc)
hiveCtx.parquetFile(parquetFile)
```

but for ocr file. I cannot find a good example to show me how to use pyspark to read.

Comment: What do you mean there's no examples? Did you actually search ORC, or instead "ocr" (which is something else). https://hortonworks.com/blog/bringing-orc-support-into-apache-spark/

Comment: sorry, it's should be orc.

Answer (score 6):

Well, there is two ways:

Spark [2.x](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.orc):

```
orc_df = spark.read.orc('python/test_support/sql/orc_partitioned')
```

Spark [1.6](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.orc):

```
df = hiveContext.read.orc('python/test_support/sql/orc_partitioned')
```

Comment: since the orc file is on hdfs. I use the hiveCtx.read.orc("hdfs://aaa/bbb/ccc").
the message show me: "malformed orc data"
but I use sql function:
hiveCtx.sql("select * from ccc")
it works, very weird...